# Setting up the database server separately from Tomcat server effects on overall performance

Tags: mysql, spring, tomcat, amazon-s3

I am curious to know the overall effects on performance if i have my Database server separately from Tomcat server(Spin a MySQL server on Amazon). Actually, I am having some performance issues and not sure if it might be the cause of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, absolutely i have found that separating the DB and application can actually uncover performance issues not evident in a co-location situation, for the network latency reasons mentioned by ck1.  In fact, if you capture stack traces during the slow operations, by sampling it will indicate the database/application code sensitive to network latency.  The use cases with performance issues ( in non co-located apps) generally make a lot of round trips to the database.  Instead try offloading the processing into the DB with a more complex query and reduce the rows returned.

Answer (score 0):

Pros of having database and app servers co-located:

- Network latency will be minimized
- You only need to maintain a single server

Cons of co-location:

- The app and database servers will contend for a common set of CPU, memory, and disk I/O resources.  For example, queries causing a spike in CPU usage will affect the app server's performance
- You have more than a single server to maintain
- It's difficult to scale horizontally

Comment: Thanks indeed for your amazing way of explanation.